# Need to solve the stochastic differential equation of Vasicek Model

Tags: credit-risk, risk-models, credit, differential-equations, vasicek

How to solve the stochastic differential equation of the Vasicek model for the analysis of credit risk? I search in the article "The Distribution of loan portfolio value" (Vasicek) but he doesn't solve the equation.

$$dA_i=\mu_i A_i dt+\sigma_i A_i dx_i$$

The solution is:

$$log A_i(T)=log A_i+\mu_i T-\frac{1}{2}\sigma_i^2T+\sigma_i\sqrt{T}X_i$$

The probability of default of the i-th loan is then

$$p_i=P[A_i(T)<B_i]=P[X_i<c_i]=N(c_i)$$

where

$$c_i=\frac{log B_i-log A_i-\mu_i T+\frac{1}{2}\sigma_i^2T}{\sigma_i\sqrt{T}}$$

and N is the cumulative normal distribution function.

Comment: The first equation is just the geometric brownian, and you can find its solution here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/873704/deriving-geometric-brownian-motions-solution

Comment: And to compute the probability, you will need to substitute the solution you have for A_i, and then isolate X,  on the left hand side.

Comment: @Magicisinthechain I went to the link you sent and tried to solve the differential equation from the beginning. T is the maturation time of the credit. The problem is that if we pass everything to the logarithm, in the formula that I wrote in the question appears $\sqrt{T}$ in $\sigma_i\sqrt{T}X_i$ and in the post that you sent me does not appear that term. Do you know how to get that missing term?

Comment: It will be Brownian motion in the solution. As BM has mean zero and variance T (standard deviation equal to square root of T), you can write it as sqrt T times standard normal for simulation purpose.